# Bird 2.0 OSPF to OSPF redistribution cost

Tags: ospf, bird

I am trying to set up bird for routing networks between my sites witch are connected with 2 L2 links.

Right now all my OSPF_INTRA are redistributed to others routers with automatic cost calculation.

I would like to specify extra cost for some network in order to "force" traffic to pass on the other link. (eg. Real-Time traffic on the first link and Bandwitdh consuming traffic on the other by tweaking cost).

Regards,

Nicolas

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thinks I found what I wanted.

I can reduce network cost by adding on the local site (where the subnet is) :

```
stubnet x.y.z.t/nn { cost 10; };
```

This way I don't have to specify extra cost and play with lesser cost.